# Get ZIP file from SFTP to Azure Datalake using Azure data factory and store it into CSV format

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-data-factory

Hi Have CSV files in zipped format in SFTP
I am able to install IR for SFTP and connection is successfull, but copying ZIP file from SFTP source to store into ADLS i getting error(import schema failed or no format define).

I have used copy data tool and dataflow for this scenerio but i am not sure how to zopy zip file from SFTP inside ADF.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below:

Change to setting "ZipDeflate" compression type in your source data set and in the sink data set of Copy activity you don't need to specify any compression configuration (Compression type is "none").

[image]

In the Copy activity sink settings, please set the copy behavior to "Flatten Hierarchy" to unzip and write the individual files.

[image]